# Use stylistic set variations only for certain glyphs

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

Some fonts include stylistic variations of certain glyphs. But it seems like there is only a global switch for these alternates, as in this example from the `fontspec` manual:

```
\fontspec{Linux Libertine}
\textsc{a} \& h \\
\addfontfeature{Alternate=0}
\textsc{a} \& h
```

Is it possible to use stylistic alternates only for individual glyphs, e.g. only for the '&'-glyph?

Comment: Hopefully in the long run these sorts of fonts move towards using CharacterVariants so that they can be toggled individually. The fontspec CharacterVariant feature corresponds to the `cv(xx)` OpenType tag, where `(xx)` is `00` to `99`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the specific example you have in mind, the simplest solution is simply to redefine `\&` as the alternate version. This is especially true of `\&`, since it's already a macro.  For the occasional other character, this route might also be best, i.e. simply define a macro to introduce the alternate.

There is a more complicated version using `\XeTeXintercharclass` that might be useful for choosing alternates for more characters.  The basic technique is explained in the XeTeX documentation (`texdoc xetex`).  Note that this solution will *not* work for LuaLaTeX, which does not support these interchar classes.

I've worked both methods in the following sample document:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}

This is an \& not alternate 

% First the simple version
\let\oldand\&
\renewcommand{\&}{\begingroup\addfontfeature{Alternate=0}\oldand\endgroup}

This is the alternate \& after redefinition.

\renewcommand\&{\oldand}

This is back to the old \&

% Now the more complicated version:
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1 % enable character classes
\newXeTeXintercharclass\myalt % create a new class
\XeTeXcharclass `\& \myalt % add & to the class
% between any character of class 0 and \myalt add the alternate feature
\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \myalt = {\begingroup\addfontfeature{Alternate=0}}
% between \myalt and any character end the group
\XeTeXinterchartoks  \myalt 0 = {\endgroup}
% between a word boundary and \myalt add the alternate feature
\XeTeXinterchartoks 255 \myalt = {\begingroup\addfontfeature{Alternate=0}}
% between \myalt and the word boundary end the group
\XeTeXinterchartoks  \myalt 255 = {\endgroup}
This is an \&  alternate. And one in the middle of a word: A\&B.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the second version and it works great.