# Glyph alternates break hyphenation

Tags: fonts, xetex, hyphenation

Alan Munn explined in 
[Use stylistic set variations only for certain glyphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28141/use-stylistic-set-variations-only-for-certain-glyphs)
how to enable glyph alternates for a certain subset of glyphs.

I'm using the second method he described (the other method isn't viable for me) and it seems to break automatic hyphenation.

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[paperwidth =   6 em,right=   1 em,left=    1 em,]{geometry}
\begin{document}
A a h coherence 
\end{document}
```

Here coherence is correctly hyphenated.
[image: correct]

Now the same with alernates switched on:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[paperwidth =   6 em,right=   1 em,left=    1 em,]{geometry}
% Now the more complicated version:
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1 % enable character classes
\newXeTeXintercharclass\myalt % create a new class
\XeTeXcharclass `\h \myalt % add h to the class
% between any character of class 0 and \myalt add the alternate feature
\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \myalt = {\begingroup\addfontfeature{Alternate=0}}
% between \myalt and any character end the group
\XeTeXinterchartoks  \myalt 0 = {\endgroup}
% between a word boundary and \myalt add the alternate feature
\XeTeXinterchartoks 255 \myalt = {\begingroup\addfontfeature{Alternate=0}}
% between \myalt and the word boundary end the group
\XeTeXinterchartoks  \myalt 255 = {\endgroup}
\begin{document}
A a h coherence 
\end{document}
```

Now hyphenation is broken.
[image: broken]

Note that this is not an artifact of the specific example, I also tried it with a longer text.

Is this a bug?

EDIT: egreg explained that this is indeed not a bug.

Is a workaround possible?
One obvious possibility is to mark hyphenation points explicitly (e.g. co-herence), but that is unpractical in a longer document.

Comment: It's not a bug: TeX and XeTeX don't try hyphenation on sequences of letters interrupted by font changes. Can't you apply the "alternation" to the whole word?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not viable: I want to globally use alternates for a certain subset of glyphs.

Comment: So the answer is: it's not a bug. I believe that this restriction can be lifted with Lua(La)TeX, which unfortunately hasn't the "interchartoks" feature.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a bug. What you get when typesetting "coherence", after the interchartoks feature has acted, is equivalent to

```
co\begingroup\addfontfeature{Alternate=0}h\endgroup erence
```

and the problem is exactly here: XeTeX won't try hyphenation past a font change.

You may "solve" it with a nasty trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\allowhyphens}{\nobreak\hskip\z@skip}
\makeatother
% Now the more complicated version:
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1 % enable character classes
\newXeTeXintercharclass\myalt % create a new class
\XeTeXcharclass `\h \myalt % add h to the class
% between any character of class 0 and \myalt add the alternate feature
\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \myalt = {\begingroup\addfontfeature{Alternate=0}}
% between \myalt and any character end the group
\XeTeXinterchartoks  \myalt 0 = {\endgroup\allowhyphens}
% between a word boundary and \myalt add the alternate feature
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \myalt = {\begingroup\addfontfeature{Alternate=0}}
% between \myalt and the word boundary end the group
\XeTeXinterchartoks  \myalt 4095 = {\endgroup\allowhyphens}
\begin{document}
\parbox{3pt}{A a h coherence}
\end{document}
```

I put "solve" in quote marks because the word that is tried for hyphenation is actually "erence" and *not* "coherence", so the result (on different words) may be incorrect.

**Note.** The answer had 255 where now is 4095. The change has been necessary from the release of TeX Live 2019.