# Extra \endgroup inexplicably in XeLaTeX interchartoks

Tags: xetex, errors

This minimal code is throwing me an `extra \endgroup` error in XeLaTeX and I can't for the life of me understand why! Does anyone have a solution to this error?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mydigitsclass 

\XeTeXcharclass `\Q \mydigitsclass


\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \mydigitsclass = {\begingroup\color{green}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mydigitsclass 0  = {\endgroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 255 \mydigitsclass = {\begingroup\color{green}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mydigitsclass 255  = {\endgroup}

\begin{document}

Qa a Q

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess that you should change 255 into 4095. This has changed with TeX Live 2019

Comment: @egreg Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary has been raised from 255 to 4095 with the TeX Live release of 2019,

XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991

If I apply the change to your code I get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The boundary class hass been 4095 not 255 for some years:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mydigitsclass 

\XeTeXcharclass `\Q \mydigitsclass


\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \mydigitsclass = {1\begingroup\color{green}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mydigitsclass 0  = {2\endgroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \mydigitsclass = {3\begingroup\color{green}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mydigitsclass 4095  = {4\endgroup}

\begin{document}

Qa a Q

\end{document}
```

The digits just to make it easier to see where the tokens are added.

Comment: Many thanks! One drawback to TeX's longevity is the very rare instance where employing old code found on TeX.se turns out to be outmoded...

Comment: @ezgranet where? (we can  leave a note about the change)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49246/glyph-alternates-break-hyphenation

Comment: @ezgranet Thanks, fixed