# XeLaTeX italic/quote kerning problem

Tags: xetex, kerning

I'm using xelatex.  I would like, I think, to alter the kerning between certain italic/math characters, and apostrophes and quotation marks.  Here's my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{minimal}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\begin{document}
$F$' $F$''
\end{document}
```

This, with xelatex, gives me:

[image: Messed-up kerning?]

That clearly seems wrong.

My question is whether it's possible to tell xelatex to alter the kerning here automatically, without inserting extra commands within the document body itself.  I have tried to alter the code given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91447/alternates-for-specific-characters-kerning/91465#91465), but to no avail.  The following doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{minimal}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\makeatletter
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\LetterClass
\newXeTeXintercharclass\QuoteClass
\@tempcnta=`\A
\loop\unless\ifnum\@tempcnta>`\Z
  \XeTeXcharclass \@tempcnta \LetterClass
  \advance \@tempcnta by 1
\repeat
\@tempcnta=`\a
\loop\unless\ifnum\@tempcnta>`\z
  \XeTeXcharclass \@tempcnta \LetterClass
  \advance \@tempcnta by 1
\repeat
\XeTeXcharclass `\'=\QuoteClass
\XeTeXinterchartoks\LetterClass\QuoteClass={\kern 2pt} % deliberately big
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$F$' $F$'' $F'$ F'
\end{document}
```

I can see what's going wrong, but I'm not sure what I should do to fix it, or whether this sort of method is wrong-headed from the start.

The solution should let me do this automatically, to whole classes of italic/math letters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I'd say `$"F$'`

Comment: @egreg Thanks.  But I wanted to do this without inserting extra commands within the document body itself.  (One reason being that I use the same body, sometimes, with both pdflatex and xelatex.)  So adding an extra '' won't work for me.  Perhaps I should also say that I want to apply the solution to a whole class of italic characters.

Comment: This is caused by combining math and text quotes. The kerning is correct if you use `\textit{F}'` for example.  `\XeTeXinterchartoks` might be a solution. Could you post what you tried for that solution too?

Comment: @RobertCraven Not with `mathspec`.

Comment: @AlanMunn I've added my ridiculous failed attempt, above.  I don't know whether I can/should be testing for italics somewhere, as per the answer to the other Q I linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two solutions to your problem.

### Use proper italics

The first questions why you would ever want to have a text quote following a math element. Either the math element contains the quote (in which case it should be realized as a prime in math mode) or the math element isn't really math, and you're using `$...$` to create text italics, which is incorrect. If the latter is the problem, then it suffices just to use `\textit` or `\emph` for your italics and the kerning will come out correctly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{minimal}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\begin{document}
$F$' $F$''

\textit{F}'
\textit{F}''
\end{document}
```

[image: ouptut of code]

### Use `\XeTeXinterchartoks`

If you absolutely need to do exactly what you are doing, it is possible to do it, but comes with some caveats, and I don't really recommend it.  We can use `\XeTeXinterchartoks` to insert space between the end of a group and the quotation marks.  Since there's no way to distinguish the end of a math group from the end of any other group in this case, this solution might add extra space in places you don't want. Here's a full example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\chardef\CharBound=\e@alloc@intercharclass@top
\makeatother
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1 % enable character classes
\newXeTeXintercharclass\mathquote % create a new class
\XeTeXcharclass `’ \mathquote
\XeTeXcharclass `' \mathquote
\XeTeXcharclass `” \mathquote
% between any character of class 0 and \mathquote
\XeTeXinterchartoks \CharBound \mathquote = {\hspace{3pt}} % purposefully large for testing
\begin{document}
$F$’
$A$’
$F$”
F’   % this is ok because no end of group.
{F}’ % fails here because you can't distinguish end-of-math from end-of-group
$F'$ % this is still ok.

\XeTeXinterchartoks \CharBound \mathquote = {\hspace{.2pt}} % Now make it more reasonable
$F$’
$A$’
$F$”
F’   % this is ok because no end of group.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you.  Your code's very helpful.  As to why I want it done: I am mentioning mathematical expressions, so the expression itself (as it were) is written within $ $, but the quotation marks are regular text quotes.  So neither a math 'prime', nor regular italics, would be appropriate.

Comment: @RobertCraven I suspected that might be the case, but I've seen too many people misuse `$...$` to get italics... :)

Comment: I've also added the following, to deal with the kerning of $F'$ (which in the Garamond I'm using was wrong).  If there's a better way, then I don't know of it:
 \def\active@math@prime{^\bgroup\primfirst@s}
{\catcode`\'=\active \global\let'\active@math@prime}
\def\primfirst@s{\hspace{1pt}\prime\futurelet\@let@token\pr@m@s}